# OSError: Invalid ELF header while importing lib.so in Python

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a program that needs to perform a lot of calculations very fast and it must be in Python for school (and I cannot use external libraries like numpy). So I figured I could build one myself in C.

lib.c

```c
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Command used to compile:
`gcc -shared -o libc.so -fPIC lib.c`

main.py

```py
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so")

print(libc.add(4, 5))
```

My system:

- Windows 11 with WSL Ubuntu (that is where I run all my commands)
- PyCharm 2023.2.1 (Professional Edition)

When I try to run `python3 main.py` I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/file/path/to/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header
```

(The line number is different because I have other imports that I don't use above.)

Comment: Are you sure that's the way to call it in Python? That seems to be calling vs. `libc` directly.

Comment: Naming your shared library `libc.so` seems like a very bad idea. That's just asking for confusing between it and the C standard library `libc.so`. Indeed, that's exactly what happened: you're accessing `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`, not `./libc.so`.

Comment: `line 13`? What you posted doesn't have 13 lines. Your code and output don't match. Post code that you actually ran and the output it actually produced.

Comment: Also, `libc` is a bad choice of name, seeing as the C standard library is also called `libc`

Comment: Not that the ELF interpreter (e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so`) needs the _real_ `libc.so` to be able to load anything so rename yours to something that does _not_ conflict with a standard library. This is a _must_ do.

Comment: I did not know that `libc.so` is already taken by the standard library. Also, I have stated that main.py includes redundant import statements and comments. That's why the line numbers don't match.

Comment: Changing line `libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so")` to `libc = ctypes.CDLL("./libc.so")` worked because now I reference the `libc.so` in my project directory. This was just a test library, I will rename it to something more fitting.